# Differentiability for function $f(x) =$ greatest lower bound of $|x-\frac 1n|$ at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let

$$f(x)=\inf\,\bigl\{|x-\frac1n|: n\in\mathbb Z^+\bigr\}\,.$$

> Is $f$ differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: Greatest lower bound (inf) over all positive integers $n$?  Then it's zero since for large $n$ and any fixed $x$ we have $|(x-1)/n|$ arbitrarily small, and so $f$ is differentiable everywhere ($C^\infty$ to boot).  Is this what you meant to ask?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking, but the question also says pay special attention to the case $x=0$, and use the definition of differentiability, so I thought I missed something. Is it differentiable at 0 and 1?

Comment: As best I can tell, if you really mean the greatest lower bound (inf) over all positive integers, $f(x)$ is identically zero, i.e., zero for all $x$.

Comment: Oh sorry... My tutor corrected.. there was a typo in the question, it should be $|x-1/n|$

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(0)=0$ because $|0-1/n|=1/n$ and so the inf over all $n$ is zero.

For negative $x$, $x-1/n$ is negative for all $n$.  $|x-1/n|=-x+1/n$ will be positive for such $x$, and its inf will be the limit as $n\to\infty$, namely $-x=|x|=f(x)$.  Because of this, $f'(0-)=-1$.

In contrast, for positive $x$ close to zero, $\inf |x-1/n|$ wiggles.  Whenever $x=1/m$ for some $m$, the inf is zero, achieved for $n=m$.  Partial quotients $${f(1/n)-f(0)\over(1/n)}$$ are zero.  If $f'(0+)$ exists, it must equal the limit of these quotients as $n\to\infty$, and thus it must be zero.  We have thus shown that $f$ is not differentiable at zero.